# How to figure out the index of a ToggleGroup's selected toggle?

Tags: javafx, radio-button, toggle

I'm trying to select an item from a list that's sorted the same way as a `ToggleGroup` I have besides it. However, I found that `toggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle())` always returns -1 (visible in the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown as I pass it). Is there another way of figuring out the index, or am I at a loss with my approach and need to figure out something completely different?

UPDATE: Apparently, for the first time an item is selected (I have this code attached to changes of `selectedToggleProperty()`), it works fine (I just get no notice of it because the elements I make visible have no proper layout). However, when an item is selected while another item already is selected, `getselectedToggle()` becomes `null`, causing aforementioned behavior.

Comment: The code you posted should work (and works fine for me). Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: the toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty fires a bit ... unconventional (to put it mildly) - when changing the selection it fires two notifications, one with (oldvalue, null), second with (null, newValue). Obviously suboptimal (though not strictly against contract, as null selected is valid state), because now we can't distinguish removal of toggles from changing selection

Comment: @kleopatra Hm. I've been guessing that. Nice to know for sure, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the JavaFX toggle controls have a property called UserData.  You should use that to create the links between the toggles and data list.   Relying on the index of the toggles in the toggle group is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be better. I'm quite new to JavaFX stuff and have many things to figure out yet. Thanks!